# No such .h file or directory(Android, Cocos2d-x, NDK)

Tags: android, c++, facebook, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am using an open source library to implement the facebook share features with cocos2d-x.
However, when I integrated with android, I have a problem that cannot load the .h file in "jni/screw" folder.
screenshot:
[image]

[image]

the file structure:

[image]

here it is my android.mk:

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    $(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d)
    $(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external)
    $(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos)

    LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

    LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

    CPP_FILES := $(shell find $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes -name *.cpp)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CPP_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)


    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \

    # _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_BEGIN
    # _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_END


    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static
    LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos2dx_store_static
    LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += screw_static
    # _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_BEGIN
    # _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_END

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

    $(call import-module,.)
    $(call import-module, extensions/cocos2dx-store)

    # _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_BEGIN
    # _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_END
```

How to solve? Thanks!

reference library screw:
https://github.com/hiepnd/Screw

Comment: You add this in .mk file     $(call import-module,screw)

Comment: I get an error when add $(call import-module,screw)

Comment: where u kept this screw

Comment: I copy it into "proj.android/jni"

Comment: why you didnot create yourself since this code using old sdk now many things change in fb sdk